# How can you deform loops in a 2d figure while staying in it?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm reading this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group) and I am confused, how it is possible to define this for a circle. In the step of construction, can we skip the homotopy equivalence of loops? I think we should be able to, since we can't realy deform curves if we talk about 2d figures.

Comment: I don't think this question is clear but I suspect that your confusion comes from how you can deform a loop to another loop while staying in the circle $S^1$ when everything looks the same. But of course you can! Think of a rubber band that you've wrapped twice, you can stretch it within the circle itself and compress other parts to stay within $S^1$, this is a different loop because you deformed it but you note you still stay wrapped around twice

Comment: If you want to see this "mathematically", consider the loops given by $f(t) = e^{it}$ and then $g(t) = e^{it^2}$ for $0 ≤ t ≤ 1$. These are different loops but can be deformed to each other, one moves "faster" than the other.

Comment: Yes, you have understood my question perfectly @OsamaGhani

Comment: Is that mal really a homotopy? I don't think squaring is smooth change @OsamaGhani

Comment: You shouldn't really think of this as genuinely squaring. But yet it is really a homotopy. You can thing of the homotopy between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ given by $H(x,t) = e^{ix^{t+1}}$. You can note that this is continuous (and in fact smooth!) and $H(x,0) = f(x)$ and $H(x,1) = g(x)$ and most importantly, $H$ is a map to $S^1$.

Comment: Also, homotopies do not have to be smooth, just continuous. Though in this case this is just a smooth homotopy. If you understand lifts of maps, this map is just lifting to $[0,1]$, performing a "straight-line homotopy" between $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x^2$ and projecting back down.